# Logical AND for LINQ to CosmosDb Sql API

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to `AND` multiple LINQ (rather lambda) `Expression`s into a `where` clause to query a local CosmosDb emulator.

The resulting query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM root 
WHERE ((root["ActivityName"] IN ("Run")) & (root["CreatedByUser"]["Id"] IN (10023))) 
ORDER BY root["CreatedOnUtc"] DESC
```

Note the bitwise `&` operator in the query. This leads to no results as the outcome despite of the fact that matching results actually exist in the CosmosDb.

When I run this query, I get the results

```
SELECT * FROM root 
WHERE ((root["ActivityName"] IN ("Run")) AND (root["CreatedByUser"]["Id"] IN (10023))) 
ORDER BY root["CreatedOnUtc"] DESC
```

The code that I am using to combine multiple lambda expressions is roughly:

```
Expression.And(first, second);
```

details for it can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/meek/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates/):

How do I combine my `Expression`s to yield a query with logical `AND` instead of bit-wise `&`?

Comment: `&&` -> `Expression.AndAlso`, `||` -> `Expression.OrElse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expression.AndAlso(first, second);` is what you need.

As you said, `Expression.And` represents a bitwise `AND` operation while `Expression.AndAlso` represents a conditional (what you called logical) `AND` operation.